# Potato and onion used in cheese & onion pasties

Tags: pastry, organization

In online recipes of cheese & onion pasties, they call for raw potato and onion mixed with grated cheddar cheese. I am wondering if the chopped potatoes and onions cook properly in the oven, don't we need to use sauteed onions and boiled potatoes?

[Link to a sample recipe](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/2422635/cheese-onion-and-potato-pasty)

Comment: Great. Now I want a pasty.

Answer (score 5):

The raw potato will definitely cook through.  If you cooked the potatoes first, they would be almost devoid of texture by the time they cooked a second time in the oven - you'd have something more akin to mashed-potato pastries on your hands.

You might want to think about sweating the onions first, though.  Sweating them would drive-off some of their moisture and would mellow the taste of your pastry filling.  Definitely not a requirement, but I think you'd prevent soggy pastry bottoms and serve-up a better tasting treat.

Also, your recipe throws-out the notion of brushing the pastry tops with milk or egg like they are interchangeable.  Milk is traditionally used to soften the the crusts of breads - an egg wash will give your pastries a rich brown top.  I have never seen a puff pastry recipe that called for a milk wash.  Stick with the egg wash - beat a large egg with 1 Tbsp. water and brush the tops of your pastries lightly before parking them in the oven.

Comment: Very good answer, I agree on both points. Milk-wash on a pasty isn't going to give a good looking result.

Comment: For a sweeter more interesting taste I would recommend that instead of raw onions you could add a teaspoon (each for each pasty) of caramelised onion relish.  The other thing I use for things like this is red onions

Answer (score 2):

both can cook properly if baked long enough. 
For example, when preparing fried potato pancakes, they contain raw potatoes and onions as well.